# Initializing a new member variable in a C++ Struct query

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to initialize a new member variable in a struct and use it elsewhere,

This is the struct

```
struct Subscription
{
    const eprosima::xtypes::DynamicType *type;
    soss::TopicSubscriberSystem::SubscriptionCallback callback;
       
};

Subscription subscription{&message_type, callback, fields};
```

---

And I was told to,

"You will need to update the definition of the Subscription struct
to match the way we are trying to initialize it there for the fields
"

I hovered over the fields variable in the code which was inside a for loop elsewhere, then vscode told me the type is

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> fields
```

so that tells me the type of the new member variable I need to add to the Subscription struct

**Just not sure what to add on the struct tho, any idea**

Comment: It may be helpful to give a little more detail on how the struct is used, and how it is "initialized."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here but did this occur to you?

```
struct Subscription
{
    const eprosima::xtypes::DynamicType *type;
    soss::TopicSubscriberSystem::SubscriptionCallback callback;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> fields;
};
```

That seems to be what you are being asked to do.